# Regex get all content between two characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to get content between symbols [ and ] even there are other same characters i need to take content between first [ and last ]. In jquery useing regex.
Thanks Advance

Comment: Why jQuery ? Are you extracting it from a string ? Or what ?

Comment: @Tafari test it on `"bla[this should[be]included]not this"`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No need for jQuery, use standard Javascript :

```
var extract = str.match(/\[(.*)\]/).pop();
```

If your delimiters are { and }, change it to

```
var extract = str.match(/{(.*)}/).pop();
```

Comment: It works thanks and could you please write same think for symbols { and }, becouse there are some of same characters and i cant understand which one i need to change to get content from inside other characters. And please put a link of good regex tutorial.

Comment: @Tafari What do you mean precisely ?

Comment: thanks. and how to detect if string starts for example [button  ???

Comment: @PaulAdamHarrison (.*) basically says "capture as many characters as possible". if you want to capture {} instead of [], then replace [ with { and ] with }. a good regular expressions tutorial (and completely free) is http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @dystroy I mean doesn't it also capture the brackets? As he wanted only the content **between symbols [ and ]**

Comment: @Tafari Read again : *"between first [ and last ]"*.

Comment: @dystroy and when it comes to your example: `bla[this should[be]included]not this`, you capture `[this should[be]included]`, which is not **BETWEEN** but rather _"text **FROM** first [ to last ]"_. Just to say I'm not using JQuery maybe thats the difference, as I don't really understand the `/` in your regex.

Comment: @Tafari Open the console of your browser (probably F12) and paste `"bla[this should[be]included]not this".match(/\[(.*)\]/).pop()`

Comment: @Tafari What you might be missing is that there's a capturing group.

Comment: No I'm using [gskinner.com](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) with the mentioned example and your pattern, and first it **removes** the `forward slashes` then it captures the string I mentioned. Well could you tell me what is the purpose of '/' in your regex?

Comment: @Tafari I suggest you read some tutorial on JavaScript regular expressions, for example [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). This is a JavaScript question, not a gskinner one.

Comment: @dystroy I put your regex into `JavaScript editing tool` and it works... Well I usually don't work with JavaScript that's way I was bit surprised that it captures the string correctly, as for example C# it would fail. Anyway thanks for the link and answers +1.

Comment: what if i have multiple?

like this
• <https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/217626378-Email-template-for-introducing-Slack|Email template for introducing Slack>
• <https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218891278-About-the-Sign-in-with-Slack-button|About the Sign in with Slack button>
• <https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218080137-Printable-poster-for-Slack-Training-Day|Printable poster for Slack Training Day>

i want to get everything between < and >

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
yourStringVariable.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]
```

Comment: now i need to detect does my string starts at [button ...

Comment: @PaulAdamHarrison Ask another question, or, better, search a little.

Comment: can you just write url of good regex tutorial ?!

Comment: nzal just gave the link to the most commonly used tutorial.