# Regex match all strings between 2 characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I tried a couple of other links like [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings) and [Regex get all content between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836706/regex-get-all-content-between-two-characters)
but they don't seem to fit this use case.

I want to get all the names, potato and tomato. Eg, from `|` to `>`.

```
text = "with <@U0D08NR3|potato> and <@U1698M96|tomato> please"
```

`text.scan((?<=|).*?(?=>))` doesnt seem to work either..

Please guide me regex gods.

Comment: [`<@[A-Z0-9]{8}\|(.*?)>`](https://regex101.com/r/X8PQ3P/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the pipe (`|`), which is now interpreted as the indicator for an alternation

Your regex with the escaped pipe:

```
(?<=\|).*?(?=>)
```

[Here you can see the result](http://rubular.com/r/MLuo5TicZQ)

Comment: Doesn't find all of the names though

Comment: How do you mean? can you give an example of what is does and does not match?

Comment: Sorry i was testing it on regex101.com and it didnt show the results correctly! It works fine on ruby :) I'll accept your answer when the timer is up Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem. The regex itself does indeed only match one occurrence, but will result in multiple matches combined with a global flag or when used with `scan()` (which will return each pattern match)

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the `|` : `(?<=\|).*?(?=>)`. Without it, the positive lookbehind means *match anything*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text.scan(/\|(\w*)\>/).flatten
# Returns => ["potato", "tomato"]
```

Not exactly sure why this works. Something to do with greedy and non-greedy matching. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)