# detecting binding expression in string by js

Tags: javascript

I have string that may contain any html elements , sentences , numbers etc stored in variable **x** now I want to find binding expression **{{ }}** and it's inner element in very effective way. I have program that mostly works fine  but fails sometime so I am searching very effective way to do it.

```
function call(x){
   var  p = 0,
        d = [],
        g = x.replace(/\s/g, '');
    for(var i = p ; i< g.length; i++){
      x = x.substr(p,x.length - p);
      f1 = x.indexOf('}*');
      f2 = x.indexOf('*{');
      if(f1 == -1 || f2 == -1){
        break;
      }
      c = x.substr(f2+1,f1-f2);
      d.push(c.replace(/}|{/g,''))
      var p = f2+(c.length+2);
    }
   return d;
 }

var x = `<div> 
          <span class="*{race}*">
            *{name}*
          </span>
      </div>`;

    console.log(call(x));
```

This works fine in most of the cases but I am searching for more effective way and small idea to do this.

- ### Please don't suggest idea using jquery

Comment: *mostly works fine but fails sometime* If you can share the test cases that are failing and succeeding, it will be possible/easier to modify/extend your existing solution itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the matches [between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19836783/1984039)

```
function call(x){
   return x.match(/{(.*)}/g);
}
```

This will return the matches including `{` and  `}`.

You can exclude them by using `(?<={)` (**match but doesn't capture preceeding character**) and `(?=})` (**match but doesn't capture succeeding character**)

```
 return x.match(/(?<={)(.*)(?=})/g);
```